# React Dropzone Uploader submitting files on drop instead of when i click submit

Tags: reactjs

Exactly what the title says. I'm using React Dropzone Uploader (https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/). I use it mainly because i need to display pictures BEFORE uploading so i give the user the chance to select which pictures he wants to upload. The problem is that as soon as i drop or select the images they are sent. How should i go about sending the images once i press submit, because rightnow all it does is Erase the items from the list.
I checked the network tab in DevTools, and it just sends a Post, when i click the little X it doesn't send anything.

```
  // Put files into the form data
  const getUploadParams = ({ file }) => {
   const body = new FormData();
   body.append(`multi-images`, file);
  
   //im guessing here is where they get posted
   return { url: `https://page.com/api/album/${categoriaSeleccionada}/${albumSeleccionado}/uploadPhotos`, body
  }
 }
   
   // called every time a file's `status` changes
   const handleChangeStatus = ({ meta, file }, status) => { console.log(status, meta, file) }
   
   // receives array of files that are done uploading when submit button is clicked
   const handleSubmit = (files, allFiles) => {
     console.log(files.map(f => f.meta))
     allFiles.forEach(f => f.remove())
   }
 
   return (
     <Dropzone
       getUploadParams={getUploadParams}
       name="multi-image"
       inputContent={(image, extra) => (extra.reject ? 'Solo archivos de imagen' : 'Clickea aquí para buscar o arrastra archivos para subirlos')}
       onSubmit={handleSubmit}
       multiple={true}
       onChangeStatus={handleChangeStatus}
       styles={{
           dropzone: { 
               minHeight: "80vh", 
               maxHeight: "80vh",
               maxWidth:"80vw",
               border: 0,
               overflowX:"hidden"
               }
           ,
           previewImage: {
               minHeight: 200,
               maxWidth: 500
           },
           preview:{
               minHeight:230,
               objectFit:"cover"
           }
           
       }}
     />
   )
 }

 export default Uploader
```

[image: Console of state change]

Is there a way i can make it wait till i press submit?

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm trying to solve it, any help?

Answer (score 0):

There is an `autoUpload` prop you can set it to `false` by default it's `true`.

[You can see props docs here](https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/props)

And you can start the uploading manually as mentioned there:

```
you can call fileWithMeta.restart whenever you want to initiate file upload
```

Comment: Yes, but i don't know how to pass files and AllFiles as parameters to buttons or some other stuff that isn't integrated in the dropzone